# laravel dompdf does not make rounded image in pdf resume

Tags: image, dompdf

I am trying to make rounded image in resume with dompdf. But I can't get 360 degree fully rounded image. How can I do it ? I write width 360%. But it does not work:(. Also I tried with pixels, but it did not work also

Comment: Does anybody know how to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean like this: `<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="border-radius: 150px;">`? If that's not working can you post a sample of the HTML/CSS you actually used?

Comment: width:150px;
            border-radius: 15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm;
            border: 2px solid white; -- instead of 15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm; I can write 360%. But it also gives the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running into a [bug present in dompdf 0.7.0 or earler](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1087). For now you'll have to manually specify the dimensions based on the size of the image. Just specify half the width/height (using the same unit space helps).

Using a square image is fairly simple and something like the following should work:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x640" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 75px; border: 2px solid white;">
```

Using a rectangular image is still possible, but requires more work. Until dompdf supports more background image attributes (like size and position) you would have to calculate the appropriate size to use for the image and radius. Using your example of a 640x480 image the following should work:

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 75px;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; left: -25px;">
</div>
```

Note that while browsers correctly avoid [curve overlaps](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-overlap) dompdf (in version 0.7.0 and earlier) does not. To ensure rendering of the border radius is consistent with browsers you will have to manually calculate the correct radius to avoid any overlaps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. All user images will have dimensions : 640x480. And In resume I write width: 150px. And how can I calculate the radius ?

Comment: You'll need to know the width and height, as well as how much rounding you want to do. Base the radisu off the dimensions of the image in the page. For example, to make a circle out of a 150px square image you would use the example from my answer. Of course 640x480 isn't a square, so unless you clip the image you won't get a circle. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want to display circle image. so if I understand true, I have to make square (for example 600x600) image if I want to get fully rounded (circle) image by using border-radius, yes ?

Comment: That would be the easiest thing to do, but you can also clip the image inside another element. The only drawback with not using a square image is that you have less control over the clipping. It's easy to generate the same output (circle around the center of the image), but if you ever wanted to focus on one side of the image or another you would have issues.

Comment: ok, thanks very much BrianS. In some resume designs I will use just square images, in other resumes circle images :)

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample of how you could render non-square images as a circle. It requires a bit more HTML/CSS but seems to work ok.

Comment: Ok, Thank You Very Much